# How to calculate Mahalanobis Distance between randomly generated values?

Tags: python, numpy, distance, mahalanobis

I'm currently learning about Mahalanobis Distance and I find it quite difficult. To get the idea better I generated 2 sets of random values (x and y) and a random point, where for all 3 mean=0 and standard deviation=1. How can I calculate the Mahalanobis Distance between them? Please find my Python code below
Many thanks for your help!

````
import numpy as np
from numpy import cov
from scipy.spatial import distance


generate 20 random values where mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1, assign one set to x and one to y

x = [random.normalvariate(0,1) for i in range(20)]
y = [random.normalvariate(0,1) for i in range(20)]
r_point = [random.normalvariate(0,1)] #that's my random point


sigma = cov(x, y)
print(sigma)
print("random point =", r_point)

#use the covariance to calculate the mahalanobis distance from a random point```
````

Comment: The `Mahalanobis_distance` Wikipedia page has a link to a Python software implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows how to compute the Mahalanobis distance of a point `r_point` to some data. The Mahalanobis distance takes into account the variance and correlation of the data you are measuring the distance to (using the inverse of its covariance matrix). Here, the Mahalanobis distance and the Euclidean distance should be very close because of the distribution of the data (0-mean and standard-deviation of 1). For other data, they will be different.

```
import numpy as np

N = 5000
mean = 0.0
stdDev = 1.0
data = np.random.normal(mean, stdDev, (2, N))   # 2D random points

r_point = np.random.randn(2)
cov = np.cov(data)

mahalanobis_dist = np.sqrt(r_point.T @ np.linalg.inv(cov) @ r_point)
print("Mahalanobis distance = ", mahalanobis_dist)

euclidean_dist = np.sqrt(r_point.T @ r_point)
print("Euclidean distance = ", euclidean_dist)
```